# Microsoft Excel - How can I convert the following text to 'date' only format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I have text in a cell with the following syntax: `Jan 6, 2022 10:18 AM`

The standard format adjustment from 'general' to 'date' does not work. I need to convert the text into a date-only format (ideally DMY). Text-to-column also doesn't work properly because of the comma.

Would I need a formula to get this to work? If so, I'd be grateful for some help.

Thanks.

Comment: The first question is whether Excel recognise your date as a date. In an adjacent cell enter `=A2+1` assuming A2 is your date. If the formula resolves to a number or another date, it means Excel has converted your text date as a date serial number. If an error occurs it means your date is only stored as a text value.

Comment: The way that Excel sometimes interprets these "long date" formats is dependant on your computer's regional language settings. In Windows control panel (not Settings) look for advanced language and regional settings. Change long date format to MMM DD, YYYY. If this doesnt work you can also try and define a custom date format in excel e.g. MMM DD, YYYY hh:mm

Comment: Tip. There's also a VBA function called `isDate()`, which returns a 1 (is recognised as a date format) or a 0. This may help you overcome the issue of Excel not converting it; it doesn't think it's a valid date format.

Comment: DATEVALUE function will help you.

Comment: @Mobus, I think you've hit the nail on the head. My language settings are English (UK), and I tried the solution submitted by Engineer Toast and it didn't work. I've just switched my language to English (US) and now the number conversion works. Thanks for the tip, that's helped a great deal.

Answer (score 2):

If that text string is in cell A1, then you can use a formula like this to convert it to a number:

```
=DATEVALUE(A1)+TIMEVALUE(A1)
```

For the example you gave of `Jan 6, 2022 10:18 AM`, this will be the value `44567.4291666667` when can then be formatted line any other date. If you don't want the number and specifically want a text-only version in the format `DMY`, you can use this:

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(A1),"dmy")
```

For the example you gave, the result is `6122`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution '@Engineer Toast' - that helped. For anyone else who stumbled upon this post, this only works if your Windows language settings are set to '**English (US)**'.

Comment: @Dan64 I am curious, can you tell if this is because the function names are in English (`DATEVALUE`) or because, as I suspect, the input string is in English? Would it work if the system language was Danish where "Jan" and "AM" are still used?